# ggplot2: decreased hue as a means to visualize a factor variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to visualize something, which currently looks similar to this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
head(ToothGrowth)
ToothGrowth$dose <- as.factor(ToothGrowth$dose)

# what I got:
p <- ggpaired(ToothGrowth, x="supp", y="len", fill="dose", line.color = "gray", line.size = 0.4)+
  scale_fill_manual(name="Dosis", labels=c("0.5","1","2"), 
                    values = c("darkorange2","olivedrab","cadetblue4"))+ # <= these colours are fixed as used in all other graphs already
  facet_grid(~dose)+
  stat_compare_means(method = "t.test", paired = TRUE)
p
```

[image: boxplots in 3 facetted grid with pairwise comparisons]

Now I would like the two boxes of the same colour differ in hue according to Condition (variable 'supp'); e.g. the OJ always appearing faded compared to VC. I know there are lot of options with colour palettes and so on, but unfortunately the colour scheme is fixed because it is set in all other figures and shared with coauthors for coherent design.

```
# what I tried so far:
p1 <- p +
  scale_alpha(name="supp", labels=c("OJ","VC"), range = c(0.5,1))
p1  # doesn't change anything

p2 <- p +
  scale_fill_hue(name="supp", labels=c("OJ","VC"), h.start = c(0.5))
p2  # overwrites existing scale_fill (and does not do a hue)

p3 <- ggpaired(ToothGrowth, x="supp", y="len", fill="dose", hue="supp",
               line.color = "gray", line.size = 0.4)+
  scale_fill_manual(name="Dosis", labels=c("0.5","1","2"), 
                    values = c("darkorange2","olivedrab","cadetblue4"))+
  facet_grid(~dose)+
  stat_compare_means(method = "t.test", paired = TRUE)
p3  # 'hue =' doesn't change anything

p4 <- ggpaired(ToothGrowth, x="supp", y="len", fill="dose", alpha="supp",
               line.color = "gray", line.size = 0.4)+
  scale_fill_manual(name="Dosis", labels=c("0.5","1","2"), 
                    values = c("darkorange2","olivedrab","cadetblue4"))+
  facet_grid(~dose)+
  stat_compare_means(method = "t.test", paired = TRUE)
p4  # 'alpha =' doesn't change anything
```

Also, usually I would do everything within a normal 'ggplot' command, but as I need this pairwise comparison I think I'm stuck with the 'ggpaired'; or am I not?

Anyone got any nice ideas on this one?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the whole thing natively in ggplot, it just takes a lot more code. You can do it like this:

```r
ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(supp, len, fill = dose, alpha = supp)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_manual(name   = "Dosis", 
                    labels = c("0.5", "1", "2"), 
                    values = c("darkorange2", "olivedrab", "cadetblue4")) +
  scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(0.5, 1), 
                       guide = guide_none()) +
  geom_line(inherit.aes = FALSE, 
            aes(supp, len, group = 0:59 %% 30), 
            color = "gray75") +
  geom_text(data = data.frame(
              x    = 1.5, 
              y    = 40, 
              dose = c("0.5", "1", "2"),
              pval = sapply(c("0.5", "1", "2"), function(x) {
                       round(t.test(len ~ supp, 
                                    data = ToothGrowth[ToothGrowth$dose == x,],
                                    paired = TRUE)$p.val, 4)})), 
            inherit.aes = FALSE,
            aes(x = 1.5, y = 40, label = paste("T test: p value =", pval)), 
            check_overlap = TRUE) +
  facet_grid(~dose) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "top",
        strip.background = element_rect(fill = "gray95", size = 0.25))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks hey, that helps a lot.
Only my R skills are not good enough to understand (and consequently adjust in a proper way) all of this code. E.g.: what exactly is this "group = 0:59 %% 30" doing?

Also, when making adjustments I often produce the error of "Cannot add ggproto objects together", as if I had missed a '+', which I thoroughly checked and I didn't... Where does that come from?

Comment: In this example, the `0:59 %% 30` is just a shorthand for the vector `c(rep(0, 30), rep(1, 30))`. As for the error, if you have not missed a `+` you have most likely missed out a parenthesis - I'm afraid I can't debug without seeing what you're attempting. Incidentally, if this post has answered your question, please consider marking it as accepted to help point other users with similar problems to a solution. Thank you

Comment: no, it's not about parantheses either, but I found the error just randomly occurs, even if the code chunk worked before and I changed nothing in it since; seems like I can omit it by highlighting the whole chunk to execute, instead just having the cursor somewhere in the code when executing.

Comment: Came across another question: How do I have to adjust the t.test command, if I am grouping by another variable (e.g. horizontal facets in facet_grid)? Let's say I did this: ToothGrowth_1 <- ToothGrowth       ToothGrowth_1$len <- ToothGrowth1$len*1.5   ToothGrowth$factor <- "A"   ToothGrowth_1$factor <- "B"   ToothGrowth$ID <- c(1:60)   ToothGrowth_1$ID <- c(1:60)    ToothGrowth_total <- rbind(ToothGrowth, ToothGrowth_1) and want to do facet_grid(factor~dose) now.

Comment: @user_20201213 that sounds fairly complex and is not really possible to answer in the comments. Effectively you would have to generate the data frame that is currently in `geom_text` with the correct p values and grouping levels for each facet using something like `map` or `mapply` to do it across the two grouping variables. If you get stuck, you may need to post another question, since this will require too much code and explanation to fit into these comments, and is really a different question from the one you posted.